# Cannot find the link path in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Why is it that I cannot view the page when I type in "http://localhost:4200/values" and I get this error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'values'

This is how my code goes.

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/starter',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          './material-component/material.module#MaterialComponentsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'starter',
        loadChildren: './starter/starter.module#StarterModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'component',
        loadChildren: './components/component.module#ComponentModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**component.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ComponentRoutes),
        DemoMaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ValuesComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentModule {}
```

**component.routing.ts**

```
export const ComponentRoutes: Routes = [
    // {
    //     path: '',
    //     component: ValuesComponent
    // },
    {
        path: 'values',
        component: ValuesComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

and this is how I call it from the link

```
const MENUITEMS = [
  { state: 'starter', name: 'Starter Page', type: 'link', icon: 'av_timer' },
  { state: 'button', type: 'link', name: 'Buttons', icon: 'crop_7_5' },
  { state: 'values', type: 'link', name: 'Values Page', icon: 'assistant' },
];

@Injectable()
export class MenuItems {
  getMenuitem(): Menu[] {
    return MENUITEMS;
  }
}
```

**html for the links**

```
<mat-list-item appAccordionLink *ngFor="let menuitem of menuItems.getMenuitem()" routerLinkActive="selected" group="{{menuitem.state}}">
        <a class="" appAccordionToggle [routerLink]="['/', menuitem.state]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'">
            <mat-icon>{{ menuitem.icon }}</mat-icon> 
            <span>{{ menuitem.name }}</span> 
            <span fxFlex></span> 
            <span class="label label-{{ badge.type }}" *ngFor="let badge of menuitem.badge">{{ badge.value }}</span> 
        </a>

        
    </mat-list-item>
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: a stackblitz would be make it so much easy to help

Comment: try moving this piece of code :

    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren:
          './material-component/material.module#MaterialComponentsModule'
      }

above this

{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/starter',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }

I suspect your route gets redirected to starter module.

Answer (score 0):

On `localhost:4200/component` you are loading ComponentModule. Once that module is loaded it will open find the `path: ''` and will load the component associated with that path in this case ValuesComponent. you have the `path: 'values'` for ValuesComponent as well.

So as per your structure, there are no routes with `localhost:4200/values`, if you need to open ValuesComponent you need to load `localhost:4200/component` or `localhost:4200/component/values`.

Comment: Is this the right way to do it in the link "{ state: 'component/values', type: 'link', name: 'Values Page', icon: 'assistant' }," because this gives me an error of  "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'component%2F%2Fvalues'"

Comment: I tried using the address bar itself using this: "http://localhost:4200/component/values" Still it's giving me an error of 404

Comment: can you create a stackblits of the issue